# PHP_SELF Code giving error message

Tags: php, mysql

i have this code here. it gives me an error of Syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'. i want to be able to display a success message on the same page rather than opening another page. please help.

```
} else {
    $query = "SELECT title, author, post, id FROM news_posts WHERE id=$id";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array ($result, MYSQL_NUM);

    $title = $row['0'];
    $name = $row['1'];
    $message = $row['2'];

    if ($num == 1) {
    echo '
    <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <p><b>Post Title :</b><br />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" value="'.$title.'" /></p>
    <p><input type="hidden" name="name" size="15" maxlength="255" value="'.$name.'" /></p>
    <p><b>Post Message :</b><br /><textarea rows="7" class="form-control" name="message">'.$message.'</textarea></p>
    <p><input type="button" value="Back" onclick="history.back()">            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" /></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$id.'" /></form>';

    } else {
        echo 'News post could not be edited, please try again.';

    }

}
?>
```

Comment: am editing an existing code. This is the initial code.

if ($num == 1) {
echo '<form action="?id=edit_news&num='.$id.'" method="post">
<p><b>Post Title :</b><br />
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" value="'.$title.'" /></p>

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Comment: You can't put `<?php` in the middle of a [PHP string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), that's the wrong context. You can interpolate if necessary. Even if that did work you're not echoing that value, just referencing it.

Comment: "so awful and dangerous" ? Kind of over-dramatizing it...

Comment: @jhilgeman - I think it's understated ... lol ... I hear women weeping and children wailing whenever I see `mysql_` used these days.  It was pretty commonplace back in the < PHP5.3 days, but now.  Use PDO, I have for the last 4 years and haven't shed any tears over it.  Even `mysqli_` makes me cringe, when it's the procedural style.

Comment: I attribute security risks to poor programming practices rather than to the extensions themselves. Even prepared statements won't protect you from bad programming (e.g. parameter manipulation).

Answer (score 0):

It's because the single quotes around PHP_SELF are interrupting the single quotes in your echo. Try this instead:

```
<form action="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '" method="post">
```

Comment: thanks... it loading but now the problem is it still opens another page for results. i want the success message to display on the same page

Comment: Means there's some other error in your code. Run php -l yourscript.php (that's a lowercase L, by the way) to do a syntax check on your code. If the syntax is okay, then check your PHP error logs.

Comment: My comment doesnt make much sense after you edited your comment above it. Anyway, if it's opening in a new page, you should open a new question and share the final HTML from your form page.